# correct way to send messages to (id *) variables or with (id *) arguments

Tags: objective-c

I have a Core Data validation method I wrote that will not compile.  I can modify the method so it compiles... but then I get runtime errors.  The two versions of the method are below (notice the missing '*' in the second version).  This version compiles but gives the runtime error "+[NSCFNumber doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff70a448e8":

```
- (BOOL)validateInitialValue:(id *)value error:(NSError **)error {
    if ( *value == nil ) {
        return YES;
    }
    if ( [*value doubleValue] < 0.0 ) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This version gives compiler warnings and errors (see warnings and errors below):

```
- (BOOL)validateInitialValue:(id *)value error:(NSError **)error {
    if ( value == nil ) {
        return YES;
    }
    if ( [value doubleValue] < 0.0 ) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

compiler errors and warnings:

```
warning: Semantic Issue: Receiver type 'id *' is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to 'id'
warning: Semantic Issue: Method '-doubleValue' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
error: Semantic Issue: Invalid operands to binary expression ('id' and 'double')
```

I finally figured that the problem may be in the calling code:

```
- (void)setInitialValue:(NSNumber *)initialValue {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"initialValue"];
    [self validateValue:initialValue forKey:@"initialValue" error:nil];
    [self setPrimitiveInitialValue:initialValue];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"initialValue"];
}
```

I changed the caller to use an '&' before initialValue and used the first version of the method, and everything worked.  So the new calling code has the one line changed to be this:

```
    [self validateValue:&initialValue forKey:@"initialValue" error:nil];
```

But is it really necessary to have the '&'??  setPrimitiveInitialValue doesn't use the '&'.  I feel like my understanding of Objective-C is just not developed enough yet and all you gurus out there will find this a trivial question with a very straight forward answer.

Comment: Others have explained the meaning of `id *`; I'd just like to add that the reason you got the runtime error you did is that an Objective-C object's first field is a pointer to its class object. So when you pass `initialValue` as the `(id *)value`, then call `[*value doubleValue]`, that's `[*initialValue doubleValue]`, and a pointer to some object/structure is the same as a pointer to its first field, so you're actually calling doubleValue on the *class* NSCFNumber — note the + sign in your runtime error, which indicates a class method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that the problem is the calling code. `id *` indicates a *pointer* to an `id` value. An object variable by itself is an `id`, so you want a pointer to that variable, which is what you get with the `&`.

The reason you pass a pointer is so that, if your validation method knows of a way to modify the value to make it valid, it can return `YES` *and also* return the valid object (by setting the variable). So, for example, if numbers less than 1 should be clamped to 0, you might do:

```
- (BOOL)validateInitialValue:(id *)value error:(NSError **)error {
    if ( *value == nil ) {
        return YES;
    }
    if ( [*value doubleValue] < 0.0 ) {
        return NO;
    }
    if ( [*value doubleValue] > 0.0 && [*value doubleValue] < 1.0 ) {
        *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

`setPrimitiveValue:` doesn't need to set variables in the calling context, so it just takes an `id`. (Very few methods work like `validateValue:forKey:error:`. Generally, they'll do it that way if they want to return a `BOOL` to indicate whether they changed something, but they still need a way to return the changed value as well.)

Answer (score 5):

`id` itself represents a pointer. So when you use `id *` you are actually referring to a pointer-to-a-pointer. The first part of [this](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) excellent tutorial explains this concept.

Chances are, this is what you are looking for:

```
- (BOOL)validateInitialValue:(id)value error:(NSError **)error {
    if ( value == nil ) {
        return YES;
    }
    if ( [value doubleValue] < 0.0 ) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Specifically, `id` is a `typedef` in [objc.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.3/runtime/objc.h) for a pointer to a generic Objective-C object: `typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;` (See also the [Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-BAJFBCCJ).)

Comment: This method is part of the Core Data validation system. The correct type for the argument is indeed `id *`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helps, but Chuck is right, I didn't get to choose the argument types.  I'm overriding a superclasses method, Chuck's answer explains this, and that answers all my questions, so his get's the "check" for this question.  thanks guys!